# AutomationId support for Xamarin Forms WPF

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried setting Automation Id to Xamarin forms Button control and it is not detected in Xamarin Forms WPF platform

Does Xamarin Forms support AutomationId for WPF platform?